# Firefox doesn't open properly (black frame)

Tags: usb, firefox

Almost every time (9/10) I open Firefox, I get this window:

[image]

Firefox is only a transparent window with a black border..

I have that problem since I forced to reboot my laptop (by pressing the shutdown button) after I formatted a usb stick in ntfs. I add some issues when umounting it.. When it's was unplugged, Ubuntu was still showing it as it was mounting.. By turning off the laptop I had error message due to the usb.. So I forced to turn it off.

Does anyone know how to fix this firefox problem ?

Thank you,
Florent.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried to remove and reinstall Firefox?

Comment: Can you try with a newly created user? Your preferences may have been corrupted.

Comment: "almost every time" what are the occasions when it doesn't happen? Please [edit] your question accordingly. Have you added any extensions?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to remove and reinstall Firefox
I didn't try with a newly created user ;)
Almost everytime -> 9 times of 10 when I open Firefox I have that issue..

Comment: Here is my current extensions : 
- AdBlocker Ultimate
- Firefox DevTools ADB Extension
- Integration to GNOME Shell
- LeechBlock NG
- Momentum
- Pinned WhatsApp Web

Comment: You've provided no basic details; what OS, product/release are you using?  What packaging system was `firefox` installed with? The default package type varies on OS/release & details you've not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I removed and reinstall Firefox a second time and now the problem is solved.

Comment: Still you haven't provided the Ubuntu version and Firefox packaging (snap or deb).